# Ember binding in helper function returns undefined

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Trying to crete a simple helper that matches user id's. One of the values is an `Ember.binding` and this one returns undefined

**controller.js**

```
App.WorkspacesTasksController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  needs: 'application',
  currentUserBinding: 'controllers.application.currentUser',

  ...

});
```

**helper.js**

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('isCurrentUser', function(currentUserId, taskUserId, options){
    currentUserId = Ember.Handlebars.get(this, currentUserId, options);
    taskUserId = Ember.Handlebars.get(this, taskUserId, options); 
    if (currentUserId === taskUserId) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

I call this in my template like so:

```
{{#isCurrentUser currentUser.id task.userObject.id}}
Matching users
{{/isCurrentUser}}
```

When I do: `console.log(currentUserId);` in my helper I get `undefined`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `if (true) return true else return false`, oh my. You could just write `return currentUserId === taskUserId`.

Comment: Good point, doesn't answer the question though.